# How to override default tooltip behavior of a C# datagridview to increase the tooltip delay for particular cells

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a windows form application with a bound datagridview in C#. I am finding a way to increase the tooltip duration for the cells of a particular column. The tooltip is being set in CellMouseEnter handler by setting cell.TooltipText property. From the research I did on the internet, it seems like I should have an external tooltip object to increase the delay. But for that, it looks like, ShowCellToolTips should be set to false. I need to have the ShowCellToolTips set to true since cell.ToolTipText is being set for other column cells in other various functions. Is there a way around for overriding the default cell.ToolTipText property for cells of a particular column and have the external Tooltip object display tooltip? The goal is to have ShowCellToolTips set to true and increase the delay for the tooltip or give user the control to close the tooltip. Is there a way to do this? Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular ToolTip control with your DataGridView which will allow you to use the ToolTip's duration property to set the amount of time the ToolTip will be displayed.

Try this:

- Add a ToolTip control to your form
- Use your DGV's CellToolTipTextNeeded (or CellMouseEnter)
  event to determine if you want to
  display your ToolTip and if so call
  the ToolTip's [ToolTip.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show.aspx)
  method.

Here's an example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellToolTipTextNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellToolTipTextNeededEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2) {     // Display the tool tip only on DGV ColumnIndex 2.
        Rectangle cellRect = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);
        toolTip1.Show("This is my ToolTip text",
                      this,
                      dataGridView1.Location.X + cellRect.X + cellRect.Size.Width,
                      dataGridView1.Location.Y + cellRect.Y + cellRect.Size.Height,
                      5000);    // Duration: 5 seconds.
    } else if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0) {
        toolTip1.Hide(this);
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ToolTipText = " Hello from column: " + e.ColumnIndex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Notice that we are not using the CellToolTipTextNeeded event to set the DataGridViewCell's ToolTipText property.

An advantage to using a ToolTip control is that you can customize the appearance and behavior of your ToolTip through the ToolTip control's properties.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Where should I clear the ToolTipText property on the DGV column. I am currently doing that in cellMouseEnter.And I have cellToolTipTextNeeded defined for the DGV column. I don't see a tooltip appear on the cell. Guess, cellToolTipTextNeeded will be fired when we get/set ToolTipText property, right ?

Comment: @SupCSharp I assumed that you had set the ToolTipProperty property of your column in the WinForm designer.  I just wanted to make sure you weren't using that property at all because you'll use a standard ToolTip control _instead_.  The CellToolTipTextNeeded event firing isn't a function of the ToolTipText property but there are circumstances where it won't fire (check the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celltooltiptextneeded.aspx)).  If that event isn't firing for you, you can drop my code in your DGV's CellMouseEnter event and it should work.

Comment: By ToolTipProperty, are you referring to the ShowCellToolTips property? If yes, I have it set to true and I want it to be true for the tooltips of other columns. Can I use the tooltip control just on the DGV column where I want to increase the delay, having ShowCellToolTIps set to true ?

Comment: @SupCSharp No, I meant [DataGridViewCell.ToolTipText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tooltiptext.aspx) property, which I believe is the same as the _cell.TooltipText_ you refered to in your original question. For my approach it doesn't matter how you've set your ShowCellToolTips property because you're not using the cell tooltip, you're using the ToolTip control.

Comment: And you can use the ToolTip control for one column and the DataGridViewCell.ToolTipText property for the other columns; just test for the column that triggered the CellToolTipTextNeeded (or CellMouseEnter) event and set the ToolTip's and ToolTipText properties accordingly.  I updated my example to show this.

Comment: I was trying to clear ToolTipText property of the DGV column. Guess that was causing the problem. I put all the code in CellMouseEnter. It works now. :) .Thanks a lot for answering my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just turnoff the `DataGridView.ShowToolTip` and handle the `MouseEnter` event.

See this microsoft article on using tooltip:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseenter.aspx

One of the problem I had with using [JayRiggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52249/jay-riggs)'s solution is that when the grid has a column that does not show the full text, there are two tooltip that are shown. One is the custom tooltip that was shown and the other is the default tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Probably someone still interested... I just made it like this, based on previous answer.

```
ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
DGViewMain.CellMouseEnter += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(DGViewMain_CellMouseEnter);
DGViewMain.CellMouseLeave += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(DGViewMain_CellMouseLeave);

private void DGViewMain_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
                Rectangle cellRect = DGViewMain.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);
                toolTip.Show("ToolTip message",
                              DGViewMain,
                              DGViewMain.Location.X + cellRect.X + cellRect.Size.Width,
                              DGViewMain.Location.Y + cellRect.Y + cellRect.Size.Height,
                              10000);    // Duration: 10 seconds.
        }

private void DGViewMain_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
                Rectangle cellRect = DGViewMain.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);
                toolTip.Hide(DGViewMain);
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).